# Dependency Injection with two independent singleton paths of same class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

please consider this dependency chart: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFeS4.jpg]

I am trying to figure out how to solve my scenario with Castle Windsor.
  There are some interfaces and classes depend of each other. Now what I need to solve register components like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWrapper>().ImplementedBy<Alfa>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("Alfa1"));
container.Register(Component.For<IWrapper>().ImplementedBy<Alfa>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("Alfa2"));
```

both of them needed own singleton path Alfa > AlfaClient > RateLimiter > ...

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWrapper>().ImplementedBy<Beta>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("Beta1"));
container.Register(Component.For<IWrapper>().ImplementedBy<Beta>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("Beta2"));
```

both of them needed second own singleton path Beta > BetaClient > RateLimiter > ...

- If I resolve Alfa1 and Alfa2, they have same own singleton
  RateLimiter
- If I resolve Beta1 anb Beta2, they have same own
  singleton RateLimiter but different then RateLimiter in Alfa.

How can I do this ?

**EDIT: more implementation details based on answers**

```
        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IIntervalRateLimiter>()
                .ImplementedBy<IntervalRateLimiter>()
                .LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IDurationRateLimiter>()
                .ImplementedBy<DurationRateLimiter>()
                .LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IRateLimiter>()
                .ImplementedBy<RateLimiter>()
                .LifestyleSingleton()
                .Named("AlfaClientRateLimiter"));

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IAlfaClient>().ImplementedBy<AlfaClient>()
                 .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IRateLimiter), "AlfaClientRateLimiter"))
                 .Named("AlfaClient")
                 .LifestyleSingleton());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IWrapper>().ImplementedBy<Alfa>()
                 .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IAlfaClient), "AlfaClient"))
                     .Named("AlfaWrapper")
                     .LifestyleSingleton());

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IClient>().ImplementedBy<Client>()
                 .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IWrapper), "AlfaWrapper"))
         .Named("Alfa1"));


        container.Register(
            Component.For<IClient>().ImplementedBy<Client>()
                 .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IWrapper), "AlfaWrapper"))
         .Named("Alfa2"));

var alfa1 = container.Resolve<IClient>("Alfa1");
var alfa2 = container.Resolve<IClient>("Alfa2");
```

Can be done without Named ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ?

```
container.Register(Component.For<IRateLimiter>().ImplementedBy<RateLimiter>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("RateLimiter"));
```

Comment: I do not, but there can be Alfa, Beta, Gama, etc...no limit of these instances. I am using installer for RateLimiter class, because it is in different assembly > library.

Answer (score 1):

Service overriding works here:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IAlfaClient>().ImplementedBy<AlfaClient>()
    .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IRateLimiter>().Is("RateLimiterAlfa"))
    .LifestyleSingleton());

container.Register(Component.For<IBetaClient>().ImplementedBy<BetaClient>()
    .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IRateLimiter>().Is("RateLimiterBeta"))
    .LifestyleSingleton());

container.Register(Component.For<IRateLimiter>().ImplementedBy<RateLimiter>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("RateLimiterAlfa"));
container.Register(Component.For<IRateLimiter>().ImplementedBy<RateLimiter>().LifestyleSingleton().Named("RateLimiterBeta"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is solve problem. Are there any possible solution without using "Named"? Is it the same as your Property ?.....DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IRateLimiter), "RateLimiterAlfa"))

Comment: Yes this is exactly the same, in fact inside of `OnComponent` method `Property.ForKey` is called internally. I don't know about any other solution.